# string name of variable(object)

Tags: c#, python

in C# `nameof(variable)` returns `"variable"`

cant i do something like this in python?

```
class ClassName:
   someVariable = "im in love with a coco"
```

if its a class, i can use `ClassName.__name__`
and this will return

```
"ClassName"
```

but what if `ClassName.someVariable.__name__`

it will raise an error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

how to get `"someVariable"`?

what code does the same as `nameof()` in python?

Comment: May be there's a better way of doing what you want to achieve. How do you want to use the result returned exactly ?

Comment: variable name as a string. thats all i want

Comment: u urself said ClassName.__name__ returns "ClassName" now "someVariable" is not a atribute to that class. which u r trying. just like C sharp u do Classname somevariable; and then u call its method same goes here.

Comment: @user3162878 well,  someVariable does have atribute to ClassName